# Using the android repo tool for a personal project

Tags: git, repository

Has anyone used Repo as a tool to manage multiple git repos in a personal project? It seems like Google created the tool so it could be used by other people, but I can't find any information on how to do so. If anyone knows how to do this or of some sort of walkthrough available, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how to use repo for your own project.

On the remote git server, create a folder and call it `manifest` or something similar, go into that directory and type git init. In the same directory as where this folder is located, you should have your other Git repositories. So for example, the folders `manifest`, `repo1`, and `repo2` are all in the same directory, and they are all Git repositories.

Now you have to configure the manifest. Go into the `manifest` folder and create a file called `default.xml`. Here's how it would look for this setup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote name="origin"
          fetch="." />

  <default remote="origin"
           revision="master" />

  <project path="repo1" name="repo1" />
  <project path="repo2" name="repo2" />
</manifest>
```

Commit the file, and your remote repository is all setup.

Now locally, create a directory called `my-repo`. Inside `my-repo`, type the command

```
repo init -u username@myserver.com:/path/to/manifest/directory/
```

This clones the `manifest` repository. Now if you type `repo sync`, repo will uses the data from the manifest to clone all of the other repositories it points to.

For more information on the manifest file, go into `my-repo` and type `repo help manifest`